# Do Azure DevOps On-prem Server 2019 support SSO

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

Please someone tell me Azure DevOps Server 2019 or 2020 supports for SSO. If it is, please tell me how to configure the SSO on On-prem server. We want to introduce single sign on for our users on Azure DevOps portal.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the [similar thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-server-on-premise-mfa2fa-or-sso-integ/943108) on Developer Community is still open.  A native SSO integration is **not implemented** yet.

Comment: Why someone voted negative on my question. Am facing this issue, So I posted here. Is there any wrong with the question?

Comment: The problem may be [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You can raise an upvote in the developer community